# D3 Cummulative Line Chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I need to achieve [this kind](http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html) of chart in D3.

Since I have four different units, I have created multiple y axis.

On hovering I displaying the line marker and the respective legends for that particular data,but on clicking the data I cant able to fix that marker at the intersection point as they did in nvd3 cummulative line chart. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 body,html{height:100%;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
 .chart-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.d3Container{
        height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

 svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.chartArea{    width: 80%;}
.legends{width:20%;}
 .contextChart {
    width:100%;
}

.chart-here
{
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(181, 201, 233);
    margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}
.chartSvg
{
    width: 100%;
    xheight: 100%;
    xposition: absolute;
}
.line {
    fill: none;
}
.background{
    fill: tomato;
    stroke: grey;
    visibility:visible !important;
}
.brush .extent {
    stroke: grey;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    height: 15px !important;
    fill:#ffffff;
    shape-rendering: auto;

}
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}

.toolTipRect rect { fill:ivory; }

</style>
<body>
<div class="chart-div">
<div class="d3Container">
        <div class = "chartArea" id = "chartArea_Chart_1234" style= "float:left">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
            <label id="title_Chart_1234" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;"></label>
            </div>
            <div id = "chart-container_Chart_1234" class="chart-here"></div>
                <div id = "contextChart_Chart_1234"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="legend_Chart_1234" class="legends" style= "float:left"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>

// response data needs to be assigned to 'var sources.array'
renderD3Chart("Chart_1234", sources);
function renderD3Chart(chartId, sources){

    var clientW = document.getElementById('chartArea_'+chartId).clientWidth; 
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 0},
    margin2 = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 0};
    var sources = sources;
    margin.left = sources.array.length * 25;
    margin2.left = sources.array.length * 25;
    var width = clientW - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 80 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;
    console.log("cl "+clientW +" -- Width "+width);
    var colors = ["Green","Blue","Red","Orange"];
    var color = d3.scale.category10(); 
    //var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y-%b-%d %H:%M").parse;
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width-280]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width-280]),
    y,y1,y2,y3,
    yArray = [y,y1,y2,y3]; 
    /*yArray = []; 
    for(var i=0; i<sources.array.length; i++){
        yArray[i] = "y"+i;
    }*/
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
        yArray[i] = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(parseDate),

        xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom").tickFormat(parseDate);
    //loop here
    var yAxis,yAxis1,yAxis2,yAxis3;
    yAxisArray = [yAxis,yAxis1,yAxis2,yAxis3];
    for(var i=0; i<sources.array.length; i++){
        yAxisArray[i] = d3.svg.axis().scale(yArray[i]).orient("left");

    }

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brush);

    //from multiAxis
    //loop here
    //var lineFun1,lineFun2,lineFun3,lineFun4;
    //var lineFunctions = [lineFun1,lineFun2,lineFun3,lineFun4]
    //for(var k=0; k<sources.array.length; k++){
    var lineFun1 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) {return yArray[0](d.value); })
    //}         
    var lineFun2 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.date);})
    .y(function(d) { return yArray[1](d.value); })

    var lineFun3 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.date);})
    .y(function(d) { return yArray[2](d.value); })

    var lineFun4 = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); })
    .interpolate("cubic")
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.date);})
    .y(function(d) { return yArray[3](d.value); }) 

    //from multiAxis    




    var svg = d3.select("#chart-container_"+chartId).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom-60)
    .attr("viewBox","0 0 500 240")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMidYMid meet")
    .attr("class","chartSvg");
    //.attr('transform','translate(210,0)' );
    var svgContext = d3.select("#contextChart_"+chartId).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height2 + margin2.top + margin2.bottom)
    .attr("viewBox","0 0 500 50")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMidYMid meet")
    .attr("class","chartSvg");

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var focus = svg.data(sources.array).append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svgContext.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50 ," + margin2.top + ")");

    // console.log("SRC "+JSON.stringify(sources.array));

    // x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    x.domain([sources.xMin,sources.xMax]);
    //x.domain([1472197994000,1472104685000]);
    //loop here
    for(var i=0; i<sources.array.length; i++){
        yArray[i].domain([sources.array[i].min,sources.array[i].max +  (sources.array[i].max * 0.2)]);
    }


    x2.domain(x.domain());

    var prevChannelLength = 0;
    var classAppender = 0;
    //loop here
    if(sources.array.length >= 1){
        for(var i=0; i<sources.array[0].values.length; i++){  
            focus.append("svg:path").attr("d", lineFun1(sources.array[0].values[i].values)).attr("class", "line line"+i)
            .attr("id",(sources.array[0].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId) ).attr("stroke",sources.array[0].values[i].color)
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").attr('stroke-width', 2);

            focus.append("g").selectAll("circle")
              .data(function(d){return sources.array[0].values[i].values})
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("r", 3)
              .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
              .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[0](dd.value)})
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke",sources.array[0].values[i].color)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("class","plotCircle"+classAppender +" "+(sources.array[0].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId));
        }
    }
    if(sources.array.length >= 2){
        prevChannelLength = sources.array[0].values.length;
        for(var i=0; i<sources.array[1].values.length; i++){    
            classAppender = i+prevChannelLength;
            focus.append("svg:path").attr("d", 
                    lineFun2(sources.array[1].values[i].values))
                    .attr("class", "line line"+classAppender).attr("id",(sources.array[1].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId) )
                    .attr("stroke",sources.array[1].values[i].color).attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").attr('stroke-width', 2)
                    ;
            focus.append("g").selectAll("circle")
              .data(function(d){return sources.array[1].values[i].values})
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("r", 3)
              .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
              .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[1](dd.value)})
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke",sources.array[1].values[i].color)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("class","plotCircle"+classAppender +" "+(sources.array[1].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId));
        }
    }
    if(sources.array.length >= 3){
        prevChannelLength += sources.array[1].values.length;
        for(var i=0; i<sources.array[2].values.length; i++){ 
            classAppender = i+prevChannelLength;
            focus.append("svg:path").attr("d", lineFun3(sources.array[2].values[i].values)).attr("class", "line line"+classAppender)
            .attr("id",(sources.array[2].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId) ).attr("stroke",sources.array[2].values[i].color)
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").attr('stroke-width', 2)
            ;

            focus.append("g").selectAll("circle")
              .data(function(d){return sources.array[2].values[i].values})
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("r", 3)
              .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
              .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[2](dd.value)})
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke",sources.array[2].values[i].color)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("class","plotCircle"+classAppender +" "+(sources.array[2].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId));
        }
    }
    if(sources.array.length >= 4){
        prevChannelLength += sources.array[2].values.length;
        for(var i=0; i<sources.array[3].values.length; i++){   
            classAppender = i+prevChannelLength;
            focus.append("svg:path").attr("d", lineFun4(sources.array[3].values[i].values)).attr("class", "line line"+classAppender)
            .attr("id",(sources.array[3].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId) ).attr("stroke",sources.array[3].values[i].color)
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").attr('stroke-width', 2)
            ;

            focus.append("g").selectAll("circle")
              .data(function(d){return sources.array[3].values[i].values})
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("r", 3)
              .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
              .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[3](dd.value)})
              .attr("fill", "none")
              .attr("stroke",sources.array[3].values[i].color)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("class","plotCircle"+classAppender +" "+(sources.array[3].values[i].color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId));
        }
    }
    //X Axis with ticks rotated
    focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")  
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-25)");

    // X Axis Label 
    focus.append("text")             
    .attr("x", width )
    .attr("y",  height  )
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("TimeStamp"); 
    //loop here     
    for(var i=0; i<sources.array.length; i++){

        focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(i*-60)+",0)")
        .call(yAxisArray[i]);
        focus.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y",  -50+(i*-60))
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(sources.array[i].name);

    }   
    focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis(x)
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
    )   
    focus.append("g")            
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis(y)
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
    )   

    var brushRange = context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brushRange")
    .attr("transform","translate(0,10)");

    brushRange.append('text')
    .attr("class","minBrush_"+chartId);
    brushRange.append('text')
    .attr("class","maxBrush_"+chartId);

    context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("height", 10);

    //changing context chart to a slider

    var svgForLegend = d3.select('#legend_'+chartId)
    .data(sources.array)
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", 300);       

    //var legendContainer = svgForLegend.append('rect').attr("height","200").attr("width","100").style("stroke","black").style("fill","none") ;

    var legendersGroup = svgForLegend.selectAll('g')
    .data(sources.array)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', function (d, i) { return 'translate(10,'+(i*70)+')' });
    var legenders = legendersGroup.selectAll('g')
    .data(function(d, i) { return d.values; })
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    //.attr('transform',function (d, i) { return -((i*margin.right)+margin.right) })
    //.attr('transform',function (d, i) { return 'translate('+(i*10)+',0)' });
    legendersGroup.append('text') //Legend Group name :: Channel Name
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("width", 5)
    .attr("height", 5)
    .attr("y",  20 )
    .attr("font-size", "10")
    .text(function (d, i) { return d.name; })
    //.text(function (d, i) { return d.type; })

    legenders.append("rect") //Each trend's Legend rect
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (i * 13) + 25; })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .on("click", function(d){  
        var legendClicked = d3.select(this).attr("id");
        console.log("legendClicked "+legendClicked);
        var active = d.active ? false : true;
        var lineOpacity = d.active ? 0 : 0.5;
        var circleOpacity = d.active ? 0 : 1;
        var legendOpacity = d.active ? 0.3 : 1;
        // hide or show the elements
        d3.select("#"+legendClicked).style("opacity", lineOpacity);
        d3.selectAll("."+legendClicked).style("opacity", lineOpacity);
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", legendOpacity);
        // update whether or not the elements are active
        d.active = active;      

    })
    .style("fill", function (d, i) { d.active = true; return d.color;})
    .attr("id",function (d, i) { d.active = true; return (d.color).replace("#","legend_"+chartId);})
    legenders.append('text') //Each trend's Legend text
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("width", 5)
    .attr("height", 5)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {return  (i * 13) + 33; })
    .attr("font-size", "10")
    .text(function (d, i) { return d.type; })

    //Mouse over - marker

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects")
    .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+",10)");
    //Tool Tip for X axis Value             
    mouseG.append('rect').attr('class','xAxis-toolTip-rect').style("opacity","0").style("fill","white").style("stroke","grey").attr("y","10")
    .attr("width",50*sources.array.length).attr("height","20"); 
    mouseG.append('text').attr('class','xAxis-toolTip').style("opacity","0"); 

    mouseG.append("path") 
    .attr("class", "mouse-line")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("opacity", "0");

    var markerGroups = mouseG.selectAll('g')
    .data(sources.array)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr("class",function(d, i) { return "G"+i })

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = markerGroups.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
    .data(function(d, i) { return d.values; })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class",  function(d, i) { return "mouse-per-line" });
    var toolTipRect = markerGroups.append("g")
    .attr('width', 100) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
    .attr('class','toolTipRect')
    .style("opacity", "0") ;

    var grpforToolTip = toolTipRect.selectAll('g')
    .data(function(d, i) { return d.values; })
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .style("opacity", "0") ;

    grpforToolTip.append("rect")
    .attr('width', 50) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('fill', '#ffffff')
    .attr('stroke', 'none')
    //.attr('class','toolTipRect')
    .style("opacity", "0") ;

    grpforToolTip.append("text"); 

    mousePerLine.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    //.style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);})
    .style("stroke", function(d) {return d.color;})
    .style("fill",  function(d) {return d.color;})
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("opacity", "0");

    //mousePerLine.append("text")
    //.attr("transform", "translate(10,3)");

    /*mouseG.append('svg:rect') // append a rect to catch mouse movements on canvas
          .attr('width', width) // can't catch mouse events on a g element
          .attr('height', height)
          .attr('fill', 'none')
          .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
          //.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)"); */

    d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' circle')
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        var xToolTip = new Date(x.invert(mouse[0]));
        //var yValue = x.invert(mouse[0])
        console.log("Hovered!");
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(0)
          .attr("r",10)
          .attr("fill",d3.select(this).attr("stroke"))
          .attr("style","opacity:0.3")

        // 
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' circle')
        .on("click", function() {
            var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
            var xToolTip = new Date(x.invert(mouse[0]));
            //var yValue = x.invert(mouse[0])
            console.log("Clicked - "+xToolTip.yyyymmddhhMMss());
        })

        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' circle')
        .on("mouseout", function() {
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr("r",3)
              .attr("fill","none")
              //.attr("style","opacity:0.3")
        })
        //

    })  
    .on('mouseout', function() { // on mouse out hide line, circles and text
        var parentChart = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        d3.select('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .mouse-line')
        .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .mouse-per-line circle')
        .style("opacity", "0");
        //d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
        //.style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect')
        .style("opacity", "0") ;
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect g')
        .style("opacity", "0") ;
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect g rect')
        .style("opacity", "0") ;
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect g text')
        .style("opacity", "0") ;
        d3.select('.xAxis-toolTip').style("opacity", "0") ;
        d3.select('.xAxis-toolTip-rect').style("opacity", "0") ;
    })
.on('mouseover', function() { // on mouse in show line, circles and text
        //setTimeout(function(){
        var parentChart = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        d3.select('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .mouse-line')
        .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .mouse-per-line circle')
        .style("opacity", "1");
        //d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
        //.style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect')
        .style("opacity", "1") ;
        //d3.selectAll(".toolTipRect text")
        //.style("opacity", "1") ;
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect g')
        .style("opacity", "1") ;
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect g rect')
        .style("opacity", "1") ;
        d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .toolTipRect g text')
        .style("opacity", "1") ;
        d3.select('.xAxis-toolTip').style("opacity", "1") ;
        d3.select('.xAxis-toolTip-rect').style("opacity", "1") ;
        console.log("b4 this "+this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id);

        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        xToolTip = new Date(x.invert(mouse[0]));
        d3.select('.xAxis-toolTip-rect').attr("x",mouse[0]+20);
        d3.select('.xAxis-toolTip').text(xToolTip.yyyymmddhhMMss()).attr("x",mouse[0]+25).attr("y",25).style("stroke","tomato");
        //console.log("Mouse Obj "+mouse);
        var toolTips = [];var G0 = [],G1 = [];
        //console.log("Mouse Obj "+mouse);
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
        .attr("d", function() {
            var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + 190;
            d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
            return d;
        });
        d3.selectAll(".toolTipRect")
        .attr("x", mouse[0]+10);

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            //if(lines[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "div"){ i=i+1;}
                //console.log(width/mouse[0])
                var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
                //console.log("h "+JSON.stringify(d.values));
                idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

                var beginning = 0;
                var end = lines[i].getTotalLength();
                var  target = null;
                while (true){
                    target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                    pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                    //console.log("Pos "+pos.x +"-"+pos.y);
                    if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
                    else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                    else break; //position found
                }

                return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y +")";

        });
        // toolTips.push({"G0":G0});toolTips.push({"G1":G1});
        for(var k=0; k<4 ; k++){
        //var k=0;
            if(d3.selectAll(".G"+k)){
                //console.log(console.log("G: "+i));
                d3.selectAll('#chart-container_'+chartId+' .G'+k+' .toolTipRect g text')
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    //if(lines[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "div"){ i=i+1;}
                        var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]),
                        bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
                        idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

                        var beginning = 0;
                        var end = lines[i].getTotalLength();
                        var  target = null;
                        while (true){
                            target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                            pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                            //console.log("Pos "+pos.x +"-"+pos.y);
                            if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                                break;
                            }
                            if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
                            else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                            else break; //position found
                        }

                        var tipPosition = mouse[0]+20+(k*50);
                        if(tipPosition > width-150) tipPosition = mouse[0]-120+(k*50);

                        d3.select(this).attr("stroke", d.color).text(yArray[k].invert(pos.y).toFixed(2));
                        d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll("rect").attr("transform","translate("+tipPosition+","+((i*20)+32)+")");
                        tipPosition = tipPosition+5;

                        return "translate("+tipPosition+","+(i*20+45)+")" ;
                    //}else return "";
                }); 
            }
        }
        //}, 3000);
    });
    //Mouse Over Marker 
    d3.selectAll('.extent').attr("y","-10") 
    // gridlines in x axis function

    function make_x_axis() {
        return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")

    }

    // gridlines in y axis function
    function make_y_axis() {
        return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yArray[0])
        .orient("left")

    }       


    function brush() {
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
        var xda = brush.x();
        //console.log("Brush "+x2.domain());
        var minBrush =new Date(brush.extent()[0]); 
        var maxBrush = new Date(brush.extent()[1]);
        d3.select('.minBrush_'+chartId)
        .text(minBrush.yyyymmddhhMMss())
        .attr("x",0)
        .attr("y",10)
        .attr("font-size", "8px");;
        d3.select('.maxBrush_'+chartId)
        .text(maxBrush.yyyymmddhhMMss())
        .attr("x",width-500)
        .attr("y",10)
        .attr("font-size", "8px");;
        var prevChannelLength = 0;
        var classAppender = 0;


        if(sources.array.length >= 1){

            for(var i=0; i<sources.array[0].values.length; i++){  
                focus.selectAll("path.line"+i).attr("d",  function(d) {
                    return lineFun1(sources.array[0].values[i].values)
                });
                //for(var j=0; j<sources.array[0].values[i].values.length; j++){  
                focus.selectAll(".plotCircle"+i)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[0](dd.value)})


            }
        } 

        if(sources.array.length >= 2){
            prevChannelLength = prevChannelLength + sources.array[0].values.length;
            for(var i=0; i<sources.array[1].values.length; i++){  
                classAppender = i+prevChannelLength;
                focus.selectAll("path.line"+classAppender).attr("d",  function(d) {
                    return lineFun2(sources.array[1].values[i].values)
                });
                focus.selectAll(".plotCircle"+classAppender)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[1](dd.value)})         
                /*focus.selectAll("plotCircle"+classAppender)
                  .data(function(d){return sources.array[1].values[i].values})
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("r", 1)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[1](dd.value)})
                  .attr("fill", sources.array[1].values[i].color)
                  .attr("stroke",sources.array[1].values[i].color);*/

            }
        }
        if(sources.array.length >= 3){
            prevChannelLength = prevChannelLength + sources.array[1].values.length;
            for(var i=0; i<sources.array[2].values.length; i++){  
                classAppender = i+prevChannelLength;
                focus.selectAll("path.line"+classAppender).attr("d",  function(d) {
                    return lineFun3(sources.array[2].values[i].values)
                });
                focus.selectAll(".plotCircle"+classAppender)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[2](dd.value)}) 
                /*focus.selectAll("plotCircle"+classAppender)
                  .data(function(d){return sources.array[2].values[i].values})
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("r", 1)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[2](dd.value)})
                  .attr("fill", sources.array[2].values[i].color)
                  .attr("stroke",sources.array[2].values[i].color);*/

            }
        }
        if(sources.array.length >= 4){
            prevChannelLength =prevChannelLength+ sources.array[2].values.length;
            for(var i=0; i<sources.array[3].values.length; i++){  
                classAppender = i+prevChannelLength;
                focus.selectAll("path.line"+classAppender).attr("d",  function(d) {
                    return lineFun4(sources.array[3].values[i].values)
                });
                focus.selectAll(".plotCircle"+classAppender)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[3](dd.value)}) 
                /*focus.selectAll("plotCircle"+classAppender)
                  .data(function(d){return sources.array[3].values[i].values})
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("r", 1)
                  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
                  .attr("cy", function(dd){return yArray[3](dd.value)})
                  .attr("fill", sources.array[3].values[i].color)
                  .attr("stroke",sources.array[3].values[i].color);*/

            }
        } 

        focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-25)");


    }

    Date.prototype.yyyymmddhhMMss = function() {
        var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
        var dd = this.getDate();
        if(dd<10)    dd='0'+dd;
        if(mm<10)    mm='0'+mm;
        return this.getFullYear()+"-"+mm+"-"+dd+" "+this.getHours()+":"+this.getMinutes()+":"+this.getSeconds() ;
    };


}



</script>
```

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VLln64mM7fVDwx0zJbOZ?p=preview) for it(Click Launch Preview in Separate Window for viewing entire chart). So please guide me how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this!!?? Did you got the solution??

Comment: Why don't you just use NVD3? If you must use a pure D3 solution, just look at the cumulativeLineChart source code in particular, the indexify method. https://github.com/COzero/nvd3/blame/feature/line-with-focus-plus-secondary/src/models/cumulativeLineChart.js#L352